# ReST philosophy - how to handle services and side effects

Tags: web-services, rest

I've been diving into ReST lately, and a few things still bug me:

1) Since there are only resources and no services to call, how can I provide operations to the client that only *do* stuff and don't *change* any data?
For example, in my application it is possible to trigger a service that connects to a remote server and executes a shell scripts. I don't know how this scenario would apply to a resource?

2) Another thing I'm not sure about is side effects: Let's say I have a resource that can be in certain states. When transitioning into another state, a lot of things might happen (e-mails might be sent). The transition is triggered by the client. Should I handle this transition merely by letting the resource be updated via PUT? This feels a bit odd.

- For the client this means that updating an attribute of this ressource might only change the attribute, or it also might do a lot of other things. So PUT =/= PUT, kind of.
- And implementation wise, I have to check what exacty the PUT request changed, and according to that trigger the side effects. So there would be a lot of checks like `if(old_attribute != new_attribute) {side_effects}`

Is this how it's supposed to be?

BR,
Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since there are only resources and no services to call, how can I provide operations to the client that only do stuff and don't change any data?

HTTP is a document transport application.  Send documents (ie: messages) that trigger the behaviors that you want.

In other words, you can think about the message you are sending as a description of a task, or as an entry being added to a task queue.  "I'm creating a task resource that describes some work I want done."

[Jim Webber](https://yow.eventer.com/events/1004/talks/1047) covers this pretty well.

> Another thing I'm not sure about is side effects: Let's say I have a resource that can be in certain states. When transitioning into another state, a lot of things might happen (e-mails might be sent).  The transition is triggered by the client. Should I handle this transition merely by letting the resource be updated via PUT?

Maybe, but that's not your only choice -- you could handle the transition by having the client put some other resource (ie, a message describing the change to be made).  That affords having a number of messages (commands) that describe very specific modifications to the domain entity.

In other words, you can work around PUT =/= PUT by putting more specific things.

(In HTTP, the semantics of PUT are effectively create or replace.  Which is great for dumb documents, or CRUD, but need a bit of design help when applied to an entity with its own agency.)

> And implementation wise, I have to check what exacty the PUT request changed, and according to that trigger the side effects.
>
> Is this how it's supposed to be?

Sort of.    Review Udi Dahan's talk on [reliable messaging](https://vimeo.com/111998645); it's not REST specific, but it may help clarify the separation of responsibilities here.